how to set properly a setOnClickListener on my adapter Firestore Recyclerview
I need to set a setonclick listener in my adapter for my RecyclerView(firestore), my activity to be show on the click is RestaurantDetails, i need to click on the restaurant cards and be directed to a page with the restaurant details
public class RestaurantAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Restaurant, RestaurantAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Activity activity;

    public RestaurantAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Restaurant> options, Activity activity) {
        super(options);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.restaurant_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Restaurant model) {
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
        holder.category.setText(model.getCategory());
        holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
        // here i should implement it i guess
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, phone, category, address, averageRating;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
            averageRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAverageRating);

        }
    }
}

thought about something like this but not working acc
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent restaurantIntent = new Intent(RestaurantAdapter.this, RestaurantDetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(restaurantIntent);
        }
    });
}


I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

If you already have a reference to Activity, try this:
// onBindViewHolder
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent restaurantIntent = new Intent(activity, RestaurantDetailActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(restaurantIntent);
        }
    });
}

